# Проблемы со спрайтами деревьев на Terrain. Спрайты черные

Tags: unity3d

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть проблема. У Terrain настроил свойство Billboard Start. Отвечает за переход дерева из 3Д режима в спрайт. В спрайт переходит, только вот спрайты черные.

[image: Черные спрайты]

Может кто сталкивался с этим или знает как победить?

Comment: Вроде проблема с материалом дерева. У нас в одном из проектов была подобная проблема, возникала при смене освещения. Помнится надо было с источником света подергать ползунки она исчезала. Проверьте шейдеры на деревьях и посмотрите как будет влиять изменение источников освещения..

Comment: Вроде разобрался, проблема с шейдером. По крайней мере после установки шейдера Nature , картинка спрайта немного изменилась. Получается для отображения спрайта, нужны правильные материалы и правильный шейдер.